# Find empty value in Table PHP

Tags: php, mysql

This the code to check a row for a value where a username = something

```
$stmt1 = $conn->prepare("SELECT likedOne FROM UserData WHERE username = ?");
$stmt1->bind_param('s',$username);
//$username = $_POST["username"];
$username ="jim";
$stmt1->execute();
$stmt1->store_result();
```

Will this statment check if the Value is empty?

```
if ($stmt1 == ''){}
```

It's not working.

Comment: `username IS NULL`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

`$stmt1->num_rows > 0`

or

`$res = $stmt1->fetch();`

```
if( !empty( $res )
{

}
```

Now your code looks like

```
$stmt1 = $conn->prepare("SELECT likedOne FROM UserData WHERE username = ?");
$username ="jim";
$stmt1->bind_param('s', $username);
$stmt1->execute();
$stmt1->store_result();

if($stmt1->num_rows > 0)
{
    //data retrive condition here
}
```

Comment: its working but each time i run it it says its empty even though ist not

Comment: the !empty part works but then says it is true for ! empty everytime.

Answer (score 0):

You can check it in number of ways,

```
if ($stmt1 === null){ } // This checks if the variable, by type, IS null.
```

OR

```
if (empty($stmt1)){ }
```

OR

```
if (!isset($stmt1)){ }
```

`!isset($stmt1)` checks if the variable isn't defined and not if it is empty or not.